# getIntent() when orientation changes - how to handle this?

Tags: android

This feels like a noob question, but in Android, when the orientation changes the Activity is destroyed and recreated, and *onCreate()* is called anew.   Internal state can be saved via a savedInstanceState bundle.   So far so good.

But in my app I have an activity which is normally invoked from another activity via *startActivityForResult()*, which passes in a bunch of parameters.  In *onCreate()* the target activity does a *getIntent()* to retrieve the passed-in data.   The problem is that when that activity is on the screen and I flip the orientation it crashes.   It's crashing in the *onCreate()* code, where it calls *getIntent()*.    I presume it's crashing because there's nothing to "get" since in that case it's being invoked from the system instead of from the other activity.

What's the correct way to handle this?   How do I tell when my *onCreate()* is being called due to an orientation change so I don't try to call *getIntent()*?  Or am I just thinking about this wrong?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can save the details that you get by the `getIntent()` method in the savedInstanceState. That means, in your `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` store the info that you use in the `onCreate()` using the `getIntent()`.  When your `activity` is newly created, in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method, the bundle `savedInstanceState` is null. So you can make a check condition in your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, if the Bundle `savedInstanceState` is null that means you need to get the data using `getIntent()` else if its not null that means there was some oritentation change and you need to get the data using the `savedInstanceState` bundle.